# Dynamic Queryset Based on Special Model Django

Tags: python, django, dynamic, django-views, django-queryset

I would like to have a page that contains product and related competitor products with it. I tried, but all the times competitor products stay same. Would you please help me?

models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
category   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
brand      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
product    = models.CharField(max_length=120)
price      = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=100)

class Comp_Product(models.Model):

product     = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
competitor  = models.URLField()
price       = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=100)
change      = models.FloatField()
stock       = models.BooleanField()
last_update = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views:

```
class ProductListView (ListView):
model = Comp_Product
context_object_name = 'comp_products'
template_name = 'products.html'

class ProductDetailView (LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView): 
model         = Product
template_name = 'product.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['comp_products'] = Comp_Product.objects.all()
    return context
```

urls.py:

```
path('product/<int:pk>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(),name='product_detail'),
path('comp_products/', ProductListView.as_view(),name='comp_products'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you say comp_products = All the Comp Products in the database.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
>>> context['comp_products'] = Comp_Product.objects.all()
    return context
```

What do you display in your template? Is it `{{comp_products}}` or

```
{% for pr in product.comp_products.all %}
  {{ pr }}
{% endfor %}
```

For this you need related_name="products" in your product field in the Comp_Product model

Comment: I just would like show related comp_products to product. Isn't enough to join both models? Both the models were joined based on the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the template that I wrote:

```
{%for comp_product in comp_products %}
 {{comp_product.competitor}} - {{comp_product.price}} - 
 {{comp_product.change}} - {{comp_product.stock}} - {{comp_product.last_update}}
            
            
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Okay, in your model, add related_name="comp_products" to this line 
`product     = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comp_products")`
then in your template `{%for comp_product in product.comp_products %}` make the for loop like this. Because you want to loop over the comp products related to a particular product. In the current version you are looping through ALL comp products in your database. When you do this, you don't need a page(url) for comp_products, which is unnecessary actually.

Comment: Also you don't need to send All comp_products to the template. So you can also delete `context['comp_products'] = Comp_Product.objects.all()` this line.

Comment: I did the changes and makemigration,migrate the model already.                         
Now, it says : Exception Value: 
Cannot resolve keyword 'comp_product' into field. Choices are: brand, category, comp_products, id, price, product, user, user_id

Comment: Make it plural, `comp_products` . Probably you said `product.comp_product` as singular.